# Codeigniter : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in Laravel project

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel-5, server, codeigniter-3

I'm getting following error:

```
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)**
```

Note : It's working in local but facing issue in production server.

```
private const API_QUERY_PARAM = "api";
private const API_FILE_QUERY_PARAM = "f";
private const API_LOG_STYLE_QUERY_PARAM = "sline";
private const API_CMD_LIST = "list";
private const API_CMD_VIEW = "view";
private const API_CMD_DELETE = "delete";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check PHP version on your production server (you can use `phpinfo();`). [Class constant visibility modifiers](https://www.php.net/archive/2016.php#id2016-12-01-3) introduced on PHP 7.1.0. Any version before it would throw syntax error.